# Contiguous hypergeometric functions

Tags: calculus, special-functions

I'm looking for relation, if there exists of course, simplifying the following sum:
$$F(\alpha,\beta;\gamma_1;x)+F(\alpha,\beta;\gamma_2;x)$$ where $F$ denotes the Gauss hypergeometric function, $\gamma_1\neq\gamma_2+n, \ n\in N.$

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there exists such a formula. In contiguity relations, parameters $a,b,c$ are always shifted by integers and different $_2F_1$'s appear therein with very specific coefficients.

Comment: @O.L., thank you for your comment

Comment: If we make some assumptions that some of the parameters are integers we can interpret 2F1() in a combinatorial sense and then use some of the combinatorial theorems; although usually for particular values of x.  Some of the combinatorial theorems all real parameters in the combinatorics.  In general it seems that your problem boils down to expressing the sum of reciprocal pochhammer functions with real parameter in a "nice" way.

Comment: You can convert from $\lambda_{1}$ to $\lambda_{2}$ cleanly by using dlmf 15.6.8  .   Examining that indicates that if d is held constant we have the direct expression for $\lambda=c-d$ in terms of some hypergeometric integral; probably a two variable form but using 15.6.1 gives a simple transition.   If you would like I could compute these; but they are not a direct answer since they relate the two cases but don't directly add them.